# Ionic/AngularJS and a simple login screen

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying out Ionic/AngularJS for the first time, and are creating a simple login with token sent via mobile.

I've got an input field for phone number and an input field for the token/code.

At first only the phone number input field is visible, but when a user request a code, the code input field should become visible.
As soon as a user has entered a 4 digit code, the button should change from "Get code" to "Log in" and call the function with 2 parameters.

This is my code so far: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PZOOBz

I'm kind of stuck with changing the button text and behavior after a user has entered the phone number.

HTML:

```
<html ng-app="Hello">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>
    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.2.4/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.2.4/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
    <script id="templates/signin.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-content>
        <form name="signInForm" novalidate>
          <div class="list list-inset">
            <label class="item item-input">
              <i class="icon ion-ios-telephone placeholder-icon"></i>
              <input type="tel" ng-model="phoneNumber" ng-minlength="4" placeholder="Your Phone Number" required>
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input" ng-if="signInForm.$valid">
              <i class="icon ion-ios-locked placeholder-icon"></i>
              <input type="text" ng-model="code" ng-minlength="4" ng-maxlength="4" placeholder="Your Code">
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="padding">
            <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-disabled="signInForm.$invalid" ng-click="signIn(phoneNumber)">Get Code</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </ion-content>
    </script>
    <script id="templates/home.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-content>
      </ion-content>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('Hello', ['ionic'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('signin', {
      url: '/signin',
      templateUrl: 'templates/signin.html',
      controller: 'SignInCtrl'
    })
    .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/signin');
})

.controller('SignInCtrl', function($scope, $state) {
  $scope.signIn = function(phoneNumber, code) {
    console.log('Sign In Phone Number', phoneNumber);
    console.log('Sign In Code', code);
    $state.go('home');
  };

  $scope.signIn = function(phoneNumber) {
    console.log('Sign In Phone Number', phoneNumber);
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an expression like {{buttonText}}.

JS:

```
angular.controller('SignInCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.buttonText = 'bla';

     $scope.changeText = function() {
           $scope.buttonText = 'foo';
     }
});
```

HTML:

```
<button ng-click="changeText()">{{buttonText}}</button>
```

Not first the button has bla as Text and after a click the text changes from bla to foo and will be rerendered.

Comment: This works for changing text, yes. I admit my question wasn't so clear, so I'm still in need of changing "ng-hide" dynamically and "required" on elements. Is that as easy in a similar way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your logic so much.

But your purpose is to change the button text when the `phoneNumber`'s length is equal to 4 or more than that, right?

so, your button code can write as:

```
<button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-disabled="signInForm.$invalid" ng-click="signIn(phoneNumber, code)">{{ phoneNumber.length >= 4 ? 'Login In' : 'Get Code' }}</button>
```

And, I have an advice.

In your controller, just write signIn function as this:

```js
$scope.signIn = function(phoneNumber, code) {
    if ( typeof code === 'undefined' ) {
        console.log('Sign In Phone Number', phoneNumber);
    }
    else {
        console.log('Sign In Phone Number', phoneNumber);
        console.log('Sign In Code', code);
        $state.go('home');
    }
};
```

Comment: My logic is not very clear. I admit that. I want to only have phone number input field at first. Button should be disabled. when phone number field is valid, button should become enabled. When button is clicked, code input field should appear and text on button should change.

Comment: Well, I see. Maybe you can write as this. I wrote it in my pen. http://codepen.io/Erichain/pen/MKOVoO?editors=101

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following,

**In HTML,**

```
  <input type="tel" placeholder="Enter Phone Number" data-ng-disabled="editing"  ng-model="phono" ng-change="calPhoNo(phono)"></br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Code" ng-model="code" ng-show="GetCode" ng-change="calSignIn(code)" ></br>
  <button data-ng-disabled="!editing" ng-click="Calgetcode()" ng-show="ShowGetCode">Get Code</button>
  <button data-ng-disabled="!editing" ng-show="ShowSignIn" ng-click="signIn()">Sign In</button></br></br>
```

**In controller,**

```
$scope.ShowGetCode=true;
$scope.calPhoNo=function(no){
  if(no.length == 4){
    $scope.editing=true;
  }else{
    $scope.editing=false;
  }
}

$scope.Calgetcode=function(){
 $scope.editing=false;
 $scope.ShowGetCode=false;
 $scope.GetCode=true;
 $scope.ShowSignIn=true;
}

$scope.calSignIn=function(no){
 if(no.length == 4){
    $scope.editing=true;
  }else{
    $scope.editing=false;
  }
}

$scope.signIn=function(){
 $location.path("/homepage");
}
```

**Refer my codpen :**

http://codepen.io/mohanapriya/pen/NrrwQN?editors=1000